# google console error `OR-IEH-01`

Tags: android, google-play

i am trying to upload an android application on google play store (google play developer console). i am adding a new visa card and press pay and it gives me this error:

> An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later. [OR-IEH-01]

any help or anyone knows why is this happening?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

i found that my google payment account was not activated. 
i activated it and the error was solved.
link for vitrification:
[google account verification](https://support.google.com/payments/contact/account_verification)

Answer (score 3):

Recently I was also having this issue, then I contacted Google Support and they gave me this link to provide required info, I posted and within 24 hours my problem was fixed.

**Link:** https://support.google.com/payments/contact/alt_account_verification

Answer (score 2):

I tried this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMQylbcln90 and it works for my case (I had expired debit card added and causing the error OR-IEH-01),
Basically, you may need to close your current payment profile in setting
https://pay.google.com/gp/w/u/0/home/settings
[image]

Comment: Amazing. Short and simple solution!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Google Play registration payment didn’t process. This can happen sometimes if a card has expired, the credit card or credit card verification (CVC) number was entered incorrectly, or if your billing address doesn't match the address in your Google Payments account.

Here’s how you can find the details of your transaction:

1. Sign in to your Google Payments account at https://payments.google.com.
2. On the left menu, select the “Subscriptions and services” page.
3. On the “Other purchase activity” card, click View purchases.
4. Click the “Google Play” registration transaction to see your payment method.
5. You can click “Payment methods” on the left menu if you need to edit the addresses on your Google Payments account.

To add a new credit or debit card to your account, you can follow the instructions on the Google Payments Help Center (https://support.google.com/payments/answer/6220309).